# What is the SQLAlchemy (ORM) command to return an object (which represents a row in the database) based on a query filter?

Tags: sqlalchemy

When I issue the command sess.query(TestClass).all()
SQLAlchemy returns the two objects I instantiated (as expected).

Code:
query_result_1 = sess.query(TestClass).all()
print(query_result_1)

output:
[<**main**.TestClass object at 0x10e9df7c0>, <**main**.TestClass object at 0x10e9df9a0>]

When I issue the command that I expected to return an object based on a filter, I instead got SQL commands...

code:
query_result_2 = sess.query(TestClass).filter(TestClass.name=='name_1')

output:
SELECT test_table.id AS test_table_id, test_table.name AS test_table_name 
FROM test_table 
WHERE test_table.name = ?

Here is the entire script:

import sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from sqlalchemy.orm import Query

print('\nsqlalchemy version:  ' + sqlalchemy.__version__)

Base = declarative_base()

class TestClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=False)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
sess = Session(engine)

obj_1 = TestClass('name_1')
sess.add(obj_1)
obj_2 = TestClass('name_2')
sess.add(obj_2)
print('\ntest instance creation (before commit):')
print('obj_1.name = %s' % (obj_1.name))
print('obj_2.name = %s' % (obj_2.name))

query_result_1 = sess.query(TestClass).all()
print('\nquery_result_1 (query all before commit):')
print(query_result_1)

# QUESTION:  What's wrong with this statement...'
# or my expectation of what it should produce?
query_result_2 = sess.query(TestClass).filter(TestClass.name=='name_1')
print('\nquery_result_2 (query (filter by name) before commit):')
print('I expected this query to return the TestClass object with name = name_1')
print('instead, I got this:')
print(query_result_2)

sess.commit()

query_result_3 = sess.query(TestClass).all()
print('\nquery_result_3 (query all after commit):')
print(query_result_3)

# QUESTION:  What's wrong with this statement...'
# or my expectation of what it should produce?
query_result_4 = sess.query(TestClass).filter(TestClass.name=='name_1')
print('\nquery_result_4 (query (filter by name) after commit):')
print('I expected this query to return the TestClass object with name = name_1')
print('instead, I got this:')
print(query_result_4)
```

Here is the terminal output:

sqlalchemy version:  1.3.17

test instance creation (before commit):
obj_1.name = name_1
obj_2.name = name_2

query_result_1 (query all before commit):

[<**main**.TestClass object at 0x10e9df7c0>, <**main**.TestClass object at 0x10e9df9a0>]

query_result_2 (query (filter by name) before commit):

I expected this query to return the TestClass object with name = name_1
instead, I got this:

SELECT test_table.id AS test_table_id, test_table.name AS test_table_name 
FROM test_table 
WHERE test_table.name = ?

query_result_3 (query all after commit):
[<**main**.TestClass object at 0x10e9df7c0>, <**main**.TestClass object at 0x10e9df9a0>]

query_result_4 (query (filter by name) after commit):

I expected this query to return the TestClass object with name = name_1
instead, I got this:

SELECT test_table.id AS test_table_id, test_table.name AS test_table_name 
FROM test_table 
WHERE test_table.name = ?

UPDATE...

I have figured out that SQLAlchemy is, in fact, returning a list of objects (in this case the list only contains one object) after I issue the query statement with the filter:   query(class).filter(class.attrbt==___).

The good news is that SQLAlchemy is (mostly) behaving the way I expected, and there is nothing wrong with my query statement.  But now I have a different question:

Why does the output from SQLAlchemy show SQL commands in response to the query().filter() statement?   In response to the query().all() statement it returns a list of objects - this is what it "should" do (and, in fact, it is what is happening) in response to the query().filter() statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example returns a list of objects because you invoked `.all()` to actually execute the query and return the results.

Your second example prints the SQL because you have created the query but you haven't executed it yet. `.filter` modifies the query but does not execute it. Compare ...

```py
thing = session.query(Account).filter(Account.id == 1)
print(type(thing))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'>
print(thing)  # SELECT so62234199.id AS so62234199_id, ...
```

... with ...

```py
thing = session.query(Account).filter(Account.id == 1).one()
print(type(thing))  # <class '__main__.Account'>
print(thing)  # <Account(id=1, created='2020-01-01 00:00:00')>
```

... and ...

```py
thing = session.query(Account).filter(Account.id == 1).all()
print(type(thing))  # <class 'list'>
print(thing)  # [<Account(id=1, created='2020-01-01 00:00:00')>]
```

For more information, see [Returning Lists and Scalars](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars) in the ORM tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer to my question.